# GitLab pipeline overriding artifacts attribute

Tags: gitlab

We have a base GitLab CI template which includes by default certain artifacts. Now we need to include this template in one of the pipelines we have and in a job we want not to pass the artifacts.

We tried this:

```yaml
artifacts: []
```

**EDIT**

Here my example:

*base.yaml*

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "build..."
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 3 weeks
    reports:
      dotenv: VERSION.env
    paths:
      - '$env:BUILD_OUTPUT_DIR\**\webconfigs'
      - '$env:MSBUILD_OUTPUT_DIR\**\_PublishedWebsites\**\*.zip'
```

*child.yaml*

```
include: 'base.yaml'

build:child:
  extends: [build]
  before_script: []
  script:
    - *run-nuget-restore
    - *build-release
  artifacts: [] # I don't need any of the atributes of the base template, but this does not work
```

but it's not valid! How can I set the artifacts attributes to empty?

Comment: do you tried to exclude them https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsexclude ?

Comment: exclude is not what I need, I just want to override from the including template. I'll update my question with an example

Answer (score 3):

Inherited keys of jobs with `extend` can be excluded with `null`.

> To exclude a key from the extended content, you must assign it to null...

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#exclude-a-key-from-extends

Example:

```yaml
.base:
  script: ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ...

test:
  extends: .base
  artifacts: null
```